# mount encryped luks partion with user home on login and not at boot

Tags: partitioning, mount, login, encryption, luks

I have an encrypted partition using LUKS mounted as home.
So all users homes are on an encrypted partition but I like to change this.
Only one user should have his data encrypted.

Suppose my user is "john" I like to mount my encrypted partition on /home/john and I like to mount it only if john logs in.

Thanks, Max
using: ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I am not sure it can be done. Experts on can prove me wrong.

Comment: I do the mount after login with `Startup applications` and the keyfile below `Documents` because my `/` is encrypted of course too, but I don't have the full home-folder on the luks-drive, only `Pictures`, `Music` and `Videos`.

Comment: don't think that it answers the question, because OP wants the whole `/home/user` folder to be encrypted.